# spring data mongodb multiple entity in same collection

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am in a situation where I have to store data belonging to multiple entities in a single collection. But when I query then back, I dont want unwanted records in my result. How can we achieve this using spring? Below is what I have done so far.

**1. I give same collection name in entity as shown below.**

```
@Document(collection = "livingThings")
@Data
public class AnimalEntity {
    //contains id, type, bla, bla
}

@Document(collection = "livingThings")
@Data
public class HumanEntity {
  //contains id, gender, address
}
```

**2. I create independent mongoRepository interfaces**

```
public interface AnimalRepository implements MongoRepository<AnimalEntity, String> {

}

public interface HumanRepository implements MongoRepository<HumanEntity, String> {

}
```

**3. And the problem is**

when I do animalRepo.findAll or humanRepo.findAll, I get all records available in the collection.

**4. What I expect**

animalRepo.findAll returns only those records where document structure is same as AnimalEntity.

Thank you very much for your time and patience to attend this query.

Comment: did you try animalRepo.findAll. By default it returns onlty the fields you have mapped in Entity class.

Comment: Yes I tried it. It has not worked yet. I am trying to figure out if it needs any additional configuration to behave in the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB automatically adds _class field to entities in a collection. Even though it is not the best solution, you can try this:

```
@Query("_class:your package name here.AnimalEntity")
public AnimalEntity findAllAnimals();
```

Comment: You are right about the _class. And I am expecting that there must be a way to tell all queries to match this class for the entity type defined in the interface implementation. If I have to write it explicitly using @Query, that would be an overhead for future maintenance and development.

Comment: Firstly, sorry for the typo, I edited it. Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421966/spring-data-mongodb-querying-multiple-classes-stored-in-the-same-collection?rq=1

Comment: @SandeepMR  ya, you should use a discriminator field  in every document and whey you do `repo.findAllByDescrimator("human")`

Comment: @Rookie007 - it would have been very helpful if you included more in your example.  What does the interface look like?  Is it capitalization sensitive?

Comment: @barrypicker its Custom repo method `findAllBy<your_field_name>(String fieldName)` it will fetch all those records which are matching with `your_field`